# if statement is equal to a value

Tags: php, if-statement

I have a result(string) of `1,1,0,0` - These come from `$sub_array['state']`

Currently all of my check boxes are checked.  How can I code the code below so that if its `1` its checked else its not? as the current code gives them all 'checked'

```
<?php

    foreach($assoc_categories as $sub_array)
    {
        if($sub_array['state'] == 1)
        {
            $checked_state = " checked='checked'";
        }                  
?>
<div>
    <input 
        class="checkbox" 
        type="checkbox" 
        name="product_category" 
        class="product_category_selector" 
        id="product_category_<?php echo $sub_array['cat_id']; ?>" 
        data-id="<?php echo $sub_array['cat_id']; ?>" 
        <?php echo $checked_state; ?> 
    /> 
    <?php echo $sub_array['name']; ?>
</div>
<input 
    class="order" 
    type="input" 
    value="<?php echo $sub_array['sorder']; ?>" 
/>
<?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: How does your "result(string) of 1,1,0,0" relate to the code? Is that the value of one of the variables?

Comment: I was going to add "...if so, which one?" but I thought that would be implied in my question. Apparently not, so: which variable is `1,1,0,0` the value of?

Comment: @IMSoP Sorry its the value of `['state'];`

Comment: Can you please make your question more clear ? If your $assoc_categories has the correct values in the $sub_array then your code it should get work. In general the code seems to be correct. Did you try to var_dump() your $assoc_categories, in order to determine what the values of this array are ?

Comment: If you know that `$sub_array['state']` is `'1,1,0,0'`, why are you comparing it to `1`? What do you expect to happen?

Comment: @IMSoP I want the states that have 1 to be checked if they have 0 I want them to be unchecked.

Comment: Did you develop any JavaScript code that may checking the check boxes ?

Comment: @MerianosNikos yes but only on submit and the data is correct in the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
if($sub_array['state'] == 1)
{
    $checked_state = " checked='checked'";
}
```

To:

```
if($sub_array['state'] == 1)
{
    $checked_state = " checked='checked'";
} else 
{
    $checked_state = "";
}
```

Basically, you are not clearing the previous value as the loop continues.

Alternatively, you could use:

```
$checked_state = ($sub_array['state'] == 1) ? " checked='checked'" : "" ;
```

Comment: Oh, well spotted. I was busy trying to understand the question, and hadn't realised it was a basic logic error!

Answer (score 0):

You forget to reset checked_state or reset it to '' if $sub_array['state'] is equal to 0.

```
<?php

    $assoc_categories = array(
        array('state'=>1, 'cat_id'=>1, 'name'=>'one',   'sorder'=>1),
        array('state'=>1, 'cat_id'=>2, 'name'=>'three', 'sorder'=>2),
        array('state'=>0, 'cat_id'=>3, 'name'=>'four',  'sorder'=>3),
        array('state'=>0, 'cat_id'=>4, 'name'=>'five',  'sorder'=>4),
    );

    foreach($assoc_categories as $sub_array)
    {
        $checked_state = $sub_array['state'] == 1 ? " checked='checked'" : '';
?>
<div>
    <input
        class="checkbox"
        type="checkbox"
        name="product_category"
        class="product_category_selector"
        id="product_category_<?php echo $sub_array['cat_id']; ?>"
        data-id="<?php echo $sub_array['cat_id']; ?>"
        <?php echo $checked_state; ?>
    />
    <?php echo $sub_array['name']; ?>
</div>
<input
    class="order"
    type="input"
    value="<?php echo $sub_array['sorder']; ?>"
/>
<?php
    }
```